# pandas assigning values bases on another columns

Tags: pandas, assign

my dataframe

```
Terrain     
M1
M2
F
G
S
B1
B2
```

I want to open another column Terrain_Type and assign values for example if Terrain is M1,M2,B1,B2 as Composite in Terrain_Type and S in Terrain as Sod in Terrain_Type and instead of F and G i would like to assign Gravel in Terrain Type column.

I have tried tried this code

```
data['Terrain_Type'] = data['Terrain'].map({['M1','M2','B1','B2']:'Composite', 'S':'Sod',['F','G']:'Gravel'})
```

But it didnt work out. Could anyone suggest me how to solve this  error in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map with a valid dictionary, and in what you have, you are using a list as a key which can be problematic. So let's suppose the dictionary is like this:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                               
data = pd.DataFrame({'Terrain':['M1','M2','F','G','S','B1','B2']}) 

d = {'Composite':['M1','M2','B1','B2'],'Sod':['S'],'Gravel':['F','G']}
```

We can create a reverse of this, which maps the terrain to the type:

```
new_dic = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        new_dic[x]=k

new_dic                                                                                           
{'M1': 'Composite',
 'M2': 'Composite',
 'B1': 'Composite',
 'B2': 'Composite',
 'S': 'Sod',
 'F': 'Gravel',
 'G': 'Gravel'}
```

Then this will work:

```
data["Terain_Type"] = data["Terrain"].map(new_dic) 

data

  Terrain Terain_Type
0      M1   Composite
1      M2   Composite
2       F      Gravel
3       G      Gravel
4       S         Sod
5      B1   Composite
6      B2   Composite
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L1 = ['M1','M2','B1','B2']
d1 = dict.fromkeys(L1, 'Composite')

L2 = ['F','G']
d2 = dict.fromkeys(L2, 'Gravel')

L3 = ['S']
d3 = dict.fromkeys(L3, 'Sod')

d = {**d1, **d2, **d3}
```

Map:

```
df['Terrain_Type'] = df['Terrain'].map(d)
```

Output:

```
  Terrain  Terrain_Type
0   M1     Composite
1   M2     Composite
2   F      Gravel
3   G      Gravel
4   S      Sod
5   B1     Composite
6   B2     Composite
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work for you :)

```
def get_terrain_type(row):
    if row in ["M1", "M2", "B1", "B2"]:
        return "Composite"
    elif row == "S":
        return "Sod"
    else:
        return "Gravel"
data["Terain_Type"] = data["Terrain"].map(lambda x: get_terrain_type(x))
```